# PYTHON BaseHTTPServer and UWSGI

Tags: python, uwsgi, basehttpserver

Please tell me in what form should I give the status of the server and the body of response from my application in uwsgi for proper work ?

```
import BaseHTTPServer
import AppLogic

class SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):


def do_GET(self):
    AppLogic = AppLogic()
    (status, response) = AppLogic.Query_get(*args)
    self.send_response(status)
    self.end_headers()
    self.wfile.write(response)
    self.wfile.flush()

def do_POST(self):
    if self.headers.getheader('content-length'):
        length = int(self.headers.getheader('content-length'))
        postData = self.rfile.read(length)
        AppLogic = AppLogic()
        (status, response) = AppLogic.Query_post(*args,postData)
        self.send_response(status)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(response)
        self.wfile.flush()

def test(Handler=SimpleHTTPRequestHandler, Server=BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer):
    httpd = Server(('localhost', 8000), Handler)
    try:
        httpd.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        httpd.server_close()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: Please, provide log or detailed information about your error.

Comment: I have no error, I do not quite understand how to properly make a decorator function that would make my application start working with uwsgi server, I thought that I will be helped to properly write the function for uwsgi. Because initially my application didn't have the logic to work with uwsgi. A lot of reading how uwsgi works, watched the code as it is implemented in Django, Flask. But I can't figure out how To adapt my application to work with uwsgi

Comment: I know that uwsgi needs this format , but I do not understand how to properly come from this function to process the method of get and post
    
    def application(env, start_response):
        start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
        return [b"Hello World"]